# How can I dynamically generate parameters for a create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model "Item", and I want to generate a bunch of Items with data taken from a CSV file. But I want to allow the user to select which data columns are used.

So my model "User" has a json attribute called Columns, telling which columns should be used from that user's CSV file. For example, if `user.columns == {"title"=>"true","category"=>"false"}`, then the Title column should be used but the Category column shouldn't.
*(Alternatively, I could only list the columns I want to include, like this: `{"title"=>"included"}`, and later do something like `user.columns.each {|c| c[0]}` to get an array of all the included columns.)*

I have a method for generating Items based on the CSV data:

```
def create
  #...
  SmarterCSV.process(file).each do |row| #this line returns an array of all the rows in the CSV file
    Item.create(title: row[:title], category: row[:category])
  end
end
```

but how can I modify the method's parameters based on the contents of `user.columns`? For the `{"title"=>"true","category"=>"false"}` example, the method would just be `Item.create(name: row[:title])`. Is it possible to dynamically generate a method like that?

I'm planning to have quite a lot of possible columns, so doing an `if` conditional for every possibility is unfeasible.

Comment: It's not clear to me the mapping between the column names and what you need in the `create` parameters. But it seems like you should modify `user.columns` to return something else (or provide another user method to do so)

Comment: @MarkThomas Sorry if I was unclear, I want to generate parameters for my `create` action based on the contents of `user.columns`. For example, if `user.columns = {"included_column"=>"true", "another_included_column"=>"true", "not_included_column"=>"false"}`, then the `create` parameters would be `Item.create(included_column: row[:included_column], another_included_column: row[:another_included_column])`. Does that make sense? `not_included_column` wouldn't be a parameter because it's false in `user.columns`

Comment: What does `row` contain?

Comment: @MarkThomas A row is just a row of the CSV file. It'll contain a bunch of different values, including "name", "category", and "tag".

Comment: In your example, you have `"title"=>"true"` resulting in a hash with a key `:name`. That's what threw me off.

Comment: @MarkThomas Sorry, that was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Item.create(name: row[:name])` also takes a hash, and can be written equivalently as `Item.create({ name: row[:name] })`

As such - you can build up the entire object in a hash each time; then [`slice`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice) off any attributes that you don't want, and then pass to `create`. So assuming you have:

```
user.columns
#=> {"name"=>"true","category"=>"false"}
```

Then you could write:

```
user_object = { "name" => row[:name], "category" => row[:category] }
#=> include all the possible attributes here

included_attributes = user.columns.select { |k, v| v == "true" }
#=> {"name"=>"true"}

Item.create( user_object.slice(*included_attributes.keys) )
#=> `Item` is created with only `name` attribute
```

---

**Edit:** as engineersmnky points out in the comments, `row` is already a hash. This simplifies it further, and you could instead just write:

```
SmarterCSV.process(file).each do |row|
  included_attributes = user.columns.select { |k, v| v == "true" }
  Item.create( row.slice(*included_attributes.keys) )
end
```

Comment: row is already a `Hash` and has keys for `name` and `category` why not just leverage that?

Comment: `keys.map(&:to_sym)` :) because the "row" keys are apparently symbols and the column keys are strings. either that or preprocess the `user.columns` with `symbolize_keys`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a method to your `User` model to return the column names as symbols:

```
class User
  def selected_columns
    columns.select{|_,v| v == "true"}.keys.map(&:to_sym)
  end
end
```

and then modify your item creation like so:

```
Item.create(row.slice(*user.selected_columns))
```